Design of a BJT Translinear-Based Square-Rooting Circuit
I'm trying to make a simple sqrt circuit to act on an input voltage and provide an output voltage without using log and antilog amplifiers. I'm trying to base my design of the translinear combination of BJTs and create something that I can sim in LTspice. I cannot create a circuit though which provides the expected output behaviour and I do not know how to provide
iBias, i2 = i4 -> iout, and iin.
I want to know what the required node connections are to make the circuit work on I1, I2, I3, I4. I have tried putting a 10mA current through I1 as the paper does not define any particular constaints only that it dictates the bias of the BJTs. I cannot figure out how I can pass a current mirror not using a reference current as I purely want vout = sqrt(vin), using a mirror on I2, I4 would appear to break this condition. I cannot figure out how to sink two currents independently from I3 and I4 without having a influence BJT's bias.






Source of above images:
Kumngern, Montree and Dejhan, Kobchai. 2008. "A New Translinear-Based Dual-Output Square-Rooting Circuit." Active and Passive Electronic Components. Hindawi Limited. https://doi.org/10.1155/2008/623970
(Direct pdf link: https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/apec/2008/623970.pdf)

Square root circuit ideas


I cannot figure out how to sink two currents independently from I3 and I4 without having a influence BJT's bias.

Current sources do the job. Let's say we scale everything to 1mA:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
That's all you need for simulation. The current through AM1 is the square root of the current through Iin.
If we wanted to build a practical circuit, Q1..Q4 need to be mounted on a block of copper for good thermal coupling and tracking, and we need a couple of op-amps to help out:

simulate this circuit
OA1 converts the ground-referenced input voltage V1 to a current through R2. OA2 drives that same current through the collector of Q3.
OA3 drives the low impedance node C such that node A is at 0V for convenience. There doesn't need to be an actual ground at C. All that's needed is a low impedance point at any suitable voltage.
Since A is at 0V, we can set the scaling current I1 through Q1 with resistor R4 to +5V.
OA4 and OA5 maintain the translinear loop invariant of equal voltages at the specific points in the loop. The op-amps isolate the base currents of Q2 and Q4 from Q1 and Q3, improving accuracy.
OA6 maintains E at the same voltage as D, ensuring that the Q3's and Q4's collectors are at the same potential, thus eliminating the influence of Early effect on Q4.
Similarly, we the node B is maintained at the same voltage (0V) as node A, also eliminating Early effect in Q2. This drive is provided by OA7 driving a current through R5. The voltage across R5 is the square root of the input voltage.
Implementation Note
The paper develops this circuit for integration on an IC. That requires auxiliary circuits quite different from what can be easily obtained outside of an IC, i.e. at board level.
Well-performing IC op-amps are not a big deal, even though they may be prohibitively expensive in an ASIC. But we're putting this circuit together on a breadboard, not on a silicon wafer.
The op-amps OA4 and OA5 need to have zero offset. They can be either zero-offset (self-nulling) op-amps, or low offset drift op-amps trimmed for zero offset.

Note that the paper's contribution is not the topology of the square-rooting translinear loop, as that has been well known decades earlier. What's new are all the auxiliary circuits that make it perform well when integrated on a bipolar IC. Those circuits are great for integration, whereas the breadboard approach shown above make sense for, well, breadboards and board-level discrete implementations.
On board level, discrete transistor pairs are a nuisance since it is hard to provide proper thermal coupling between transistors in the pair as well as resistance to thermal gradients on the board. In an IC, those are relatively well solved problems - the small scale of the IC, and the ability to vary the device geometry and layout all make it easy. Tossing extra transistors at the problem is cheap on an IC, but outside of an IC it is easy to make things worse precision-wise.

All of that is great, but the icing on the cake (for me) is that transimpedance amplifier top right, keeping Q2 collector biased near zero. While playing with the original design, I found that the largest error is due to Q2's Vce being very different from Q1, and your transimpedance amplifier eliminates that perfectly, and provides a zero-referenced output voltage too! Nice answer, very nice.
